# the generalized Marcum Q-function in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, random, scipy

I am trying to plot a CDF of a random variable that contains the generalized Marcum Q-function

[image]

How can I write the Q-function in python or which library it exist

I was searching in sci.py but I didn't manage to find solution

Comment: I'm on thin ice here, hence just posting as comment: In `scipy.stats`, you have this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/continuous_ncx2.html. So the cumulative form can be obtained by the `cdf` method of the `ncx2` object defined in that model.
I don't know however, if it is exactly the same form as you require.

Comment: THere is Marcum Q implementation in the  SymPy, see https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html for details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Dr. V, scipy provide [non-central chi-squared distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ncx2.html#scipy.stats.ncx2).

But one thing that is not explicit in your formula is what is the order of the Marcum-Q function you want to compute. So I keep this as an input parameter for the function

The CDF of the non-central chi-squared distribution is $1 - Q[df/2](sqrt(nc), sqrt(x))$. Where `df` is the degrees of freedom, and `nc` is the non-centrality parameter.

```
from scipy.stats import distributions
def F(nu, k, x, A=1):
  return distributions.ncx2.cdf(df=nu, nc=2*k, x=x**2*(2*(k+1)/A))
```